# How to publish a windows application the way a web application is published in .NET?

Tags: .net, web-applications, msbuild

By publishing I mean generation of a directory with all the code of the windows application, similarly to how a web application is published in a dedicated directory under `$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites` when the code is built with a given out directory (i.e. OutDir is passed to the build).

Right now I have essentially "stealed" the publishing code from `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` and placed it in our own targets file, which the windows application project imports. This way we publish some of our windows applications and unit tests under special directories - _PublishedApplications and _UnitTests.

I wonder how others solve the same problem - you build code with the shared bin directory (using OutDir build parameter) and wish to publish stuff that is not web applications.

**EDIT 1**

Allow me to clarify. On a build server a solution is built into a shared bin directory. This is because the CI build sets the `OutDir` build property to some value. Since this value is shared among all the projects in the solution, all of them place their build products into this directory. For a web application X it means, that there is no longer a bin folder under it. For a library/exe project it means there is no longer bin\Debug (or bin\Release) under it. All goes to this shared bin.

However, a web application gets a special treatment. As soon as its build products are placed into this shared bin, msbuild invokes targets from `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` which does the following:

1. Creates the folder `_PublishedWebsites\X` under the shared bin directory
2. Copies all the binaries needed by the web application into `_PublishedWebsites\X\bin`
3. Copies all the content files needed by the web application into `_PublishedWebsites\X`
4. Copies any other files as needed to either `_PublishedWebsites\X` or `_PublishedWebsites\X\bin`

That is what I call publishing. It is not really publishing to the web server, it is more like packaging for deployment.

I need the same for the non web applications. I implemented it by creating my own targets file and essentially duplicating the logic of `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`, but cannot be I am the only one who needed that and that everyone else does the same. Must be a better way.

Comment: Publishing is a lot more than setting the `<OutDir>` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dotnet it is simple - use the publish command.

This would be exactly the same command line as for `dotnet build`, only replace `build` with `publish`.